# Using Laravel mutators as validation when setting a value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Let's say I have an object with a field called cake. This cake object as a type field that is a varchar and must have the format cake-(any number). Could I then use a mutator to make sure that someone is not setting a string with the wrong format?

For example if another developer tries to do `cake->type = c2;` should I throw an error from my mutator or should this be done somewhere else?

Is this best practice or is there a better place to validate setters?

Comment: You could potentially set up some custom validation within the model. Good article here: http://daylerees.com/trick-validation-within-models/

Answer (score 0):

You can use model events in your models, like at the end of your model, outside of your class:

```
Cake::saving(function($model) {
    if($model->type != [your condition])
       return false; 
       // In this case your model won't be saved, also you can throw an error here
});
```

It's more like a prevention, not a validation exactly. But it's better, because your models could be created as a child in a relationship, so these methods will run every time, you don't have to call separate validations.

(You can write in your class also, in a `public static function boot()..` method..)

You a have few model events, like: `creating`, `saving`, `updating`, `deleting` and some others as I know.